# Postgres Left Join with and condition too slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I have two tables

`sleeps`

| SleepId | SleepTime | WakeupTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 141b40f7-688b-43af-8266-3cc4612b8f98 | 2021-11-25 22:27:30 | 2021-11-25 22:16:30 |
| e91bd0f8-688b-43af-8266-dsc4612f8490 | 2021-11-24 22:27:30 | 2021-11-24 22:16:30 |

`sleepupdates`

| SleepId | SleepTime | WakeupTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 141b40f7-688b-43af-8266-3cc4612b8f98 | 2021-11-25 22:27:30 | 2021-11-25 22:16:30 |

`sleepupdates` table might contain some SleepIds and if it does, I need to pick that **WakeupTime** (from `sleepudates` and not `sleeps` table).

I thought left join should work for this with coalesce but it looks like its taking too much time!

It seems to scan the left table before it filter based on condition

```
select s."SleepId", s."BedTime", s."SleepTime", coalesce(su."WakeupTime", s."WakeupTime") from sleeps s
left join sleepupdates su
on s."SleepId"=su."SleepId"
and s."SleepId"='141b40f7-688b-43af-8266-3cc4612b8f98
```

I need help in above query.

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`

[image]

`Text Format`

```
explain (analyze,buffers,format text) select s."SleepId", s."BedTime", s."SleepTime", coalesce(su."WakeupTime", s."WakeupTime") from sleeps s
left join sleepupdates su
on s."SleepId"=su."SleepId"
and s."SleepId"='141b40f7-688b-43af-8266-3cc4612b8f98';
```

```
                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Right Join  (cost=123483.97..130997.74 rows=850932 width=40) (actual time=444.144..628.801 rows=852809 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (su."SleepId" = s."SleepId")
   Join Filter: (s."SleepId" = '141b40f7-688b-43af-8266-3cc4612b8f98'::uuid)
   Rows Removed by Join Filter: 21396
   Buffers: shared hit=98037, temp read=4910 written=4848
   ->  Seq Scan on sleepupdates su  (cost=0.00..559.89 rows=21289 width=24) (actual time=0.005..2.806 rows=21396 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=347
   ->  Hash  (cost=106199.32..106199.32 rows=850932 width=40) (actual time=438.068..438.068 rows=852809 loops=1)
         Buckets: 65536  Batches: 32  Memory Usage: 2067kB
         Buffers: shared hit=97690, temp written=4786
         ->  Seq Scan on sleeps s  (cost=0.00..106199.32 rows=850932 width=40) (actual time=0.007..263.471 rows=852809 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=97690
 Planning time: 0.237 ms
 Execution time: 667.356 ms
(14 rows)
```

`Indexes on sleepupdates`

```
CREATE INDEX "sleepupdates_SleepId_idx"
    ON public.sleepupdates USING btree
    ("SleepId" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
-- Index: sleepupdates_SleepId_unique

-- DROP INDEX public."sleepupdates_SleepId_unique";

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "sleepupdates_SleepId_unique"
    ON public.sleepupdates USING btree
    ("SleepId" ASC NULLS LAST, "Status" COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default
    WHERE "Status" = 'PENDING'::text;
-- Index: sleepupdates_UserId_idx

-- DROP INDEX public."sleepupdates_UserId_idx";

CREATE INDEX "sleepupdates_UserId_idx"
    ON public.sleepupdates USING btree
    ("UserId" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

The **SleepId** is primary key in `sleeps` table

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: What you have added is an image, not formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning every row of sleeps.  The `s."SleepId"='141b40f7-688b-43af-8266-3cc4612b8f98` condition needs to be in a WHERE clause, not in the ON.